# How to make any object in SWT blur?

Tags: java, swt

Can we make a group or anything for that matter blur(inactive but seen with a lighter shade), and on a click of button it should be seen proper in SWT.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `setEnabled(false)` on SWT controls makes them display in a lighter color (and be not responsive).

Note: Unfortunately this does not work for Tables and Trees. You have to set colors for those manually.

Comment: I called setEnabled(false) and the table became unresponsive. But the color did not change

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for Tables and Trees. You have to set colors for those manually.